# PHP block shortcut in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, shortcut

How can I open a basic PHP block in Visual Studio Code, like so - `<?php ?>`?

In [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) I simply type **php** and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the block is created. But I can't find the same shortcut for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You could create your own snippet? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Lol, I know that I could type it, but isn't it more efficient with a shortcut? I guess in Sublime it's just basic functionality. I'll try option with custom snippet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add a custom user snippet to Visual Studio Code:

- Open "Preferences"
- User Snippets
- Select **html.json (HTML)**
- Paste the following custom snippet:

  ```
  "php": {
      "prefix": "php",
      "body": [ "<?php $1 ?>" ],
      "description": "php tag"
  }
  ```

Comment: It works. Unfortunately php related snippets don't work immediately after inserting php tag. The coursor needs to be moved outside of tags and then back in between tags. Only then I can use php related snippets.

Answer (score 14):

Use:

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Open menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Snippets*
3. Search and select "html.json"
4. Now *paste* this code in {}:

   ```
    "php": {
        "prefix": ["<?", "<? ", "php"],
        "body": [ "<?php $1 ?>" ],
        "description": "php tag"
    }
   ```

Now you can use `"<?"` or `"<? "` or `"php"`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in order to quickly order the space.

```
    "php": {
    "prefix": ["<?", "php"],
    "body": [
        "<?php",
        "",
        "$0",
        "",
        "?>"
    ],
    "description": "php tag"
}
```

You get something like this:

```
        <?php
        
        (code here)
        
        ?>
```