# Creating a PHP code snippet in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm a little confused. The file I'm editing in VScode is a php file and the code snippet below will not work if I put the snippet in the php.json, but it does, if I insert the snippet into the html.json?!

Can someone please explain why the code snippet works in one and not the other?

```
"php": {
   "prefix": "php",
   "body": [ "<?php $1 ?>" ],
   "description": "php tag"
}
```

Credit goes to the [original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683991/6746919) for the above code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP block shortcut in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624475/php-block-shortcut-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I would recommend you to commend this question on bottom of the above mentioned question so that the person who had answered the question will explain you in detail. so that his answer will be very much useful for future also.

Comment: You're never going to type `<?php` when already in PHP context. It only makes sense outside. VSCode embedded languages support is not particularly sophisticated and it'll just assume HTML.

Comment: @Thomas Easo I did and I got down voted and told to create a new question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've got a php file with a mix of html and php so I want to be able to type php then tab and get <?php  ?>. If what you replied was meant to be an answer to my question it failed, sorry?!

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "it failed". Do you need a more thorough explanation? Or you disagree with the statement that `<?php ?>` is not valid in PHP context? The latter is [easy to prove](https://3v4l.org/Rmq1J).

Comment: No not at all. I'm just learning so this is all new to me so what you said was over my head. From the little I know to create a snippet in VScode you have to edit the relevant json file. So if I want a snippet which means I don't have to type out <?php ?> every time within a php file I have to edit the relevant json file for that language, that's according to the VScode help docs anyway.

Comment: But obviously I'm misunderstanding something. I've got it to work but I had to put the snippet in HTML.JSON. You seemed to be making an additional point that makes no sense to the very limited knowledge I have. I'm currently following a tutorial on WP development on Udemy so I'm only following what the tutor is doing.

Answer (score 2):

PHP was initially designed as a simple templating language for HTML. Where you used to have static HTML:

```
<p>Hello, World!</p>
```

… you could replace part of it with a dynamically generated value:

```
<p>Hello, <?=$name?>!</p>
^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^ HTML
            ^^^^^^        PHP
```

Although it's a full-fledged language nowadays, it still maintains the same basic embedded language syntax.

The PHP interpreter does not really care if the outer language is HTML or anything else because it just ignores everything that's outside PHP tags. It reads the source file and prints it as-is, but when it finds an opening PHP tag it starts parsing and executing as PHP code whatever it finds inside the tag. So it's possible to use PHP as templating engine for anything: CSS, JavaScript, XML, plain text, binary files... Whatever. PHP doesn't need to know or care.

A text editor like VisualStudio Code faces a different situation because the surrounding language is relevant to programmer thus it's relevant to editor. If it only cared about PHP code, everything outside PHP tags would neither have syntax highlighting nor code intellisense—not cool.

In practice there're two issues with that:

- There isn't a standard reliable way to identify the outer language from within an editor.
- Implementing code intelligence for multiple languages within the same file is a complex problem.

Since probably 99% of the times we have PHP inside HTML most editors just assume the outer language in a `.php` file is HTML and call it a day.

---

Now, why does my entry for `<?php ?>` in my `php.json` snippet file not work at all (but works when in `html.json`) when it's clearly a PHP tag (and clearly not an HTML tag)?

Because when you trigger the snippet you are in HTML context. Your caret is here:

```
<p>Hello, |</p>
```

… so VSCode searches in HTML snippets.

If your caret was e.g. here:

```
<p>Hello, <?=|?>!</p>
```

… it should work flawlessly because you're in PHP context thus VSCode searches in PHP snippets (try it!). But that's a pointless feature because you don't want to insert PHP tags when you're already in PHP mode—that generates invalid PHP because you cannot nest PHP tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to build upon Álvaro González's great explanation by proposing a workaround for those 99% whose outer php file context **is** HTML.
You can **add your php tag snippet** to your **HTML snippets**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- Create a file eg: php.code-snippets in "/home/user-name/.config/Code/User/snippets/" , then paste:

```
{
    "PHP Tag": 
    {
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": ["<?php \n\t$1 \n?>"],
        "description": "Place the php tag."
    }
}
```

- then ctrl+shift+p, choose "developer:reload window" to restart VsCode